# Why does my ASP.NET Project/Website refuse to run when certain files are open in the IDE?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I ran my website earlier, and all was fine.

Then, after inspecting it with Resharper (and noting some issues it found, but doing nothing about them - changing no code at all), ran the site again - or tried to - and got:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please 

review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond 

application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:    

Line 56:            </controls>
Line 57:        </pages>
Line 58:        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
Line 59:        <sessionState timeout="360"/>
Line 60:        <httpHandlers>

Source File: C:\MembersOrderEntryRedux\MembersOrderEntry\MembersOrderEntry\mobile\web.config    Line: 58 

Show Additional Configuration Errors:
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5491
```

Why would this be a problem now, when it wasn't before?

**NOTE:** I did notice that yesterday, this legacy project had a **PROJECT** menu in Visual Studio 2013, which today is no longer **PROJECT** but **WEBSITE** Why would that change, from one day to the next?

But, again, it ran fine the first time.

I then simply closed the files I had opened because Resharper had found "errors" in them (ASP, Javascript, and VB Compiler), F5'd again, and voila! - it runs fine again, as before.

Why does it care which files are open in the IDE?

BTW, I said "errors" re: what Resharper found because these don't prevent building or running (as long as the files it finds problems in are not open in the IDE).

The fragility of this is really giving me the fantods. It's hard to have faith my project will run from one time to the next, when it is so temperamental.

What set of actions need I avoid to prevent these will-of-the-wisp obstructions?

Comment: You are using source control right? Look at the commits and who did them and the messages etc. Things don't magically change on their own.

Comment: No - no source control; nobody could have touched it - except maybe Resharper, though even that I doubt.

Comment: Then perhaps the lesson here is *use source control*.

Comment: Is it the case that you have to have a certain file selected in Solution Explorer for it to run correctly? IOW, if you've got some files selected, the waste material impacts the rotating electrical appliance?